# How to inject into a BitmapDescriptor

Tags: android, roboguice

I am using Roboguice.

How do I inject into a BitmapDescriptor?

usually without Roboguice I do:

```
BitmapDescriptor file;
BitmapDescriptor resource;

file = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromFile(new File...)
resource  = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable...)
```

is there a way to inject these values ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose there might be a few ways to do this.  It all depends on how you'd want to approach it.

One way would be to use `Named` bindings.  Lets say for BitmapX which is referenced by `R.drawable.bitmap_x` you could do.

```
bind(BitmapDescriptor.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("BitmapX")).toProvider(new Provider<BitmapDescriptor>() {
            @Override
            public BitmapDescriptor get() {
                return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bitmap_x);
            }
        }).
```

In your code you could then use this.

```
@Inject
@Named("BitmapX")
private BitmapDescriptor bitmapX
```

or this

```
@Inject
public SomeConstructor(@Named(BitmapX) BitmapDescriptor bitmapX) {
}
```

You could also create your own Annotation for each Bitmap you'd want injected.  You'd have to create an annotation for every different BitmapDescriptor you want loaded.

```
@Target({ METHOD, CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@BindingAnnotation
public @interface BitmapX {
}
```

Then you'd define in your module like so

```
bind(BitmapDescriptor.class).annotatedWith(BitmapX.class).toProvider(new Provider<BitmapDescriptor>() {
            @Override
            public BitmapDescriptor get() {
                return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bitmap_x);
            }
        }).
```

Then again you could now use this.

```
@Inject
@BitmapX
private BitmapDescriptor bitmapX
```

or

```
@Inject
public SomeConstructor(@BitmapX BitmapDescriptor bitmapX) {
}
```

In both cases you'll have to define a binding for each of the BitmapDescriptor you'd want injected.  Honestly I'm not sure if this is worth the trouble but it's definitely doable.